# Difference between two sets of data in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2000

I am trying to work out the difference between customers that have been billed in the last 3 months and the whole customer base. I have been able to calculate the customers that have been billed using the following SQL

```
DECLARE @DateFrom AS DATETIME
SET @DateFrom = 
   CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + 
   '-' + 
   CAST(MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-01', 120)

DECLARE @DateTo AS DATETIME
SET @DateTo = 
   CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + 
   '-' + 
   CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-01', 120)

SELECT DISTINCT
    i.CustomerCode
FROM
    Invoice AS i
WHERE
    (i.InvoiceDate > @DateFrom AND i.InvoiceDate < @DateTo)
```

The table that I will be comparing against will be the Customer table which also has a CustomerCode field.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

After spending ages trying to figure this out and just after a few minutes of posting this message here I found a solution. Using the NOT IN clause!

```
SELECT
    c.CustomerCode
FROM
    [Customer] AS c
WHERE
    c.CustomerCode NOT IN (
SELECT DISTINCT
    i.CustomerCode
FROM
    [Invoice] AS i
WHERE
    (i.InvoiceDate >= @DateFrom AND i.InvoiceDate < @DateTo))
```

In my senario this appears to perform quicker then the steps mentioned below when I tested each in Management Studio.

Comment: and what exactly do you want? A list of all customer who haven't been billed in the last 3 months? Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Exactly that. I am using SQL Server 2000. Is there a better solution to the one that I currently have?

Comment: No, I think in SQL Server 2000, that's about as easy as it gets.

Answer (score 3):

you can improve your date handling with:

```
WHERE i.InvoiceDate >= DATEADD(mm,-3,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0))
    AND i.InvoiceDate < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

notice I used >= on the start, you are missing rows on the start date with a time of 00:00:00.

to get all the customers that did not have invoices within the last 3 full months, you could also write it this way:

```
SELECT
    c.CustomerCode
FROM Customer                c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Invoice  i ON c.CustomerCode=i.CustomerCode
        AND i.InvoiceDate >= DATEADD(mm,-3,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0))
        AND i.InvoiceDate < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)
WHERE i.CustomerCode IS NULL
```

Comment: date handling tip is good.
But the query should be changed so that the InvoiceDate range check is part of the LEFT OUTER JOIN's ON clause and not in the WHERE.

Comment: @van, duh, yea it won't work with it in the WHERE, it has to be in the ON

Answer (score 2):

To get the customers that have not being billed during some period of time:

```
SELECT      c.CustomerCode
FROM        [Customer] AS c
LEFT JOIN   [Invoice] AS i
        ON  c.CustomerCode = i.CustomerCode 
        AND i.InvoiceDate > @DateFrom AND i.InvoiceDate < @DateTo
WHERE       i.CustomerCode IS NULL
```

Though I would replace the `@DateFrom and @DateTo` date range checks with suggestion of KM to avoid using variables.